# What do "source" and "sink" mean?

Tags: meaning, technical, science

I do not understand "source" and "sink" in the following passage. I tried to look up a dictionary and google translate but it is not clear. Could anyone explain it for me? the passage:

> This application note describes how to use the EFM32 Current Digital to Analog Converter (IDAC), a peripheral that can source or sink a configurable constant
>   current.

Thank you!

Comment: What did a dictionary say for source and sink? Though the technical definitions are not the first ones, look through all the meanings of the words. Also consider that they're being used metaphorically.

Comment: It's terminology used in electronics, and it transferred from there to computers.  A "source" is just that, a provider of voltage, data, or some other entity.  A "sink" is where the stuff goes.  (Of course, with data all to often much of it goes down the toilet, but that's an entirely separate issue.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These terms are often used in computer hardware, software and testing.

- *source* would mean to produce and
- *sink* to consume something, in this case a configurable constant current of electricity.

Comment: The [Current source and sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_sources_and_sinks) is answer what I find. According the link, they explained that: _the term current source refers to a boundary where charge flows from locations where it is not measured to locations where it is measured. A current sink may refer to the boundary where charge flows from locations where it is measured to locations where it is not measured_